# Understanding details in Pushdown Automaton (PDA)

Tags: pushdown-automaton

I've recently been set a task to create a Pushdown Automaton that is based on a Finite Automaton that I created beforehand. (I didn't actually do it successfully, which is why I was given a working copy by my tutor)

I'm having trouble understand a part which is included in both diagrams.

""The first is what exactly does an arrow mean when it is joint to a state but just points right back to it, am I right in thinking that this is checking that the language entered beforehand (in my case 0-9) is correct (this arrow is pointing back at a terminal state)""

I've tried doing my research but unfortunately I have come up with nothing that can really explain it to me in basic terms, I even tried "Finite Automaton for dummies" And still nothing! I've also checked questions that may have my answer and nothing there.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding your question. What do the double double quotes (`""`) represent?

Comment: sorry they are there just so people can see the actual question

Answer (score 1):

If you mean a loop like the two arrows marked with “1” on the following diagram:

[image: Finite state machine example]

then those are just normal state transitions, the only special aspect is that the next state is the same as the previous state. I.e., if we are at the S_2 state above, then while the input contains “1”, we consume those ones and stay in S_2. Only after a “0” comes from the input we move to S_1.

In case of your specific machine, you probably should stay in the terminal state while the input contains any digit (“0–9”).